# Wordpress render image from custom wysiwyg

Tags: wordpress, image, wysiwyg, wp-editor

So I have a custom `wp_editor()` in my woocommerce product category which is working fine.  I mainly want it to add images that will be rendered in the category pages.  I can add images from the media, and save them.

However I'm having trouble displaying the image on the front end.  I can get the content out of the wysiwyg like this...

```
$topBanner = get_woocommerce_term_meta( $id, 'product_cat_top_banner_wysiwyg', true );
```

This gives me the whole img tag.  But if I use `echo $topBanner` it literally echos the img tag out to the page.

How can I get it to render the actual image out to the page rather than the img tag.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure about the code u using but I had the same problem when using wp_editor the data of the media was presented : /img674589/ and did not show the image in the site
what I used to fix it was wordpress Sanitize:

```
<?php wp_kses_post( $data ); ?>
```

http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/wp_kses_post